# Rails link_to in eco template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, marionette, eco

I'm trying to create a link in an eco template using Backbone Marionette with a rails backend. I'm trying to let the user download the data in CSV/XLS. If I was in a regular rails view I could do `<%= link_to "CSV", surveys_path(format: "csv") %>`.

Does anyone know how I could generate a link_to piece like above within an eco template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually opted to use the js-routes gem to set the route in my view and then just access it in the template via `<%= @csv_route %>`.

```
@model.set(csv_route: Routes.survey_path(@model.get('id'), {format: 'csv'}), xls_route: Routes.survey_path(@model.get('id'), {format: 'xls'}))
```